# API to get the working hours data from google calendar settings

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-settings

Can we get the Working hours data from google calendar settings.
I have gone through the APIs of calendar

[google calendar settings api](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/settings)

but didn't get the required data with this. Attaching the image for reference

[Image FYI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOrL2.png)

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to retrieve the working hours right now.

Comment: I too didn't find the results related to working hours. I checked for calendar settings API and ACL APIs

Comment: My time zone and other persons times zones are different and  having their own  work hours. Now is there anyway to calculate to get the matched work hours with respect to organizer(intiator)

Comment: l.o.l. @ google. The fact this isn't automatically included in the API after they added it as a feature. #catfood.

Comment: I opened a feature request for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231620767.